# If fast charging a device causes the lithium battery to drain faster, why doesn’t that apply to Tesla super chargers?

Tags: battery-charging

Some iPhone chargers are 'fast' chargers which deliver more than a single amp and charge the iPhone faster.

Tesla Superchargers are known for charging a battery fast as well.

But since charging fast drains the lithium ion battery faster, does that mean Tesla isn't getting its maximum mileage potential? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "charging fast drains the battery faster"?  Charging is the opposite of draining.

Comment: @TimWescott Most likely OP is referring to reduction in total capacity.

Comment: The OP needs to clarify the question because it is unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast charging doesn't drain the battery at all, it *charges* it. However it does reduce mileage, for two reasons - firstly because the battery doesn't receive a full charge, and secondly because it wears the battery out faster so the total lifespan and number of miles driven is reduced.

The Tesla Supercharger can charge from 0% to 80% in about 40 minutes. After that the charge rate must be gradually reduced to prevent the battery voltage going too high, so the last 20% takes another 35 minutes. So you can get full mileage per charge, but not if you want it *fast*.

But how much does it reduce lifespan? In Tesla's case not much, for several reasons:-

1. The cells used in Tesla batteries are optimized for (relatively) high power rather than highest possible capacity, so they can withstand higher charge current without damage.
2. Tesla batteries have active thermal control to keep the battery at optimum temperature, and not just cooling. A cold battery cannot be charged as fast, so in cold weather the car may deliberately *heat* the battery while on route to a charger.
3. 80% in 40 minutes is an average charge rate of 1.5C, which isn't actually that fast. High power Lithium-ion batteries are usually rated for a 'standard' charge rate of 1C, and up to 5C maximum (that's a theoretical charge to 80% time of under 10 minutes!).
4. What really reduces a Lithium-ion battery's lifespan is charging to 100% and leaving it there, particularly at high temperature. So fast charging to 80% and driving away is probably less damaging than slow to charging to 100% and leaving the car in the garage for a week.

That's the theory, here's the proof:-

[Find Out How This Tesla Model S Is Holding Up After 400,000 Miles](https://insideevs.com/news/339628/find-out-how-this-tesla-model-s-is-holding-up-after-400000-miles/)

> **at 194,000 miles... The first battery only saw 6 percent
>   degradation** before it was replaced, **even though Tesloop visits**
>   **Superchargers daily**. The second battery didn't perform as well, losing
>   an estimated 22 percent before replacement. However, the company
>   admitted that it charged the car to 95 or 100 percent every time,
>   which isn't recommended by Tesla and has been proven to deplete
>   battery capacity more rapidly.

Comment: Some followup questions: 1) Why do batteries get worse when idle at 100%? The battery doesn't stay at high temperature simply because of how much charge it's holding, so I don't get your conclusion. 2) Are you stating that delivering more current to a battery increases the chances of reducing battery capacity?